# DataTables export to CSV but maintain styling / force formatting

Tags: excel, datatables, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

Using datatables and the tabletools plugin which works.

I am however looking for a way to also export the styling of the table if this is possible?

I am creating an 'online' version of a commonly used excel sheet used in my company. Users keep on messing up the formulae / deleting rows etc and although I can create something much simpler and maintainable in the browser, its needs to be the same styling as before once exported.

Just wondering if this is possible?

I could also use the copy to clipboard feature of tabletools if that helps the case.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a dumb format. It only knows about data and is not meant to store formatting information.
If you want to preserve the formatting, you need to export your file as XLS or XLSX (or PDF if you don't want people to edit the file).